# How to add whitespace before a text in HamlJS

Tags: ruby, node.js, haml, frontend

I need to add a simple whitespace before the "Sign Up" to give a space between the icon and the text.

```
%a{ href: "#" }
  %i.fa.fa-user
    Sign Up
```

Does exist a scape to adding whitespace and the Haml compiler don't recognize It like a indentation? I'm using gulp-haml with the visionmedia/haml.js compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that a better approach to this is to add a margin-right to the icon. To do this add a class to the icon (I'm using `.app-signup-icon` here)

```
%a{ href: "#" }
  %i.fa.fa-user.app-signup-icon
    Sign Up
```

Then define the css rule with a margin-right in your css file:

```
.app-signup-icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be the right way to do this! I'll do this way, but I discovered how to add whitespace before a string: `= " Sign Up"`. Thank you!